# excel 2010 vba, path/file access error

Tags: vba, excel, dir

In the below `excel 2010 vba` if the answer the the prompt is no then the files in te folder, then the folder are deleted.  However, I am getting a `path/file access error` when I run the `vba`.  Specifically the `RmDir MyFolder` line is highlighted, but when I step-through the code the correct directory appears in the variable `MyFolder` and I can write new files to the directory.  What am I missing?  Thank you :).

Also, if I manually navigate to the directory, I can remove it.

```
iYesNo = MsgBox("Do the patients and barcode match the setup sheet?", vbYesNoCancel)
      Select Case iYesNo
             Case vbYes
             GoTo Line2
             Case vbNo
             MsgBox ("Doesn't match! Please enter again")
             MyFolder = Directory ' delete all txt files in the folder
             MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.*")
             Do Until MyFile = ""
             Kill MyFile
             MyFile = Dir
             Loop

               RmDir MyFolder  ' delete folder
             GoTo Line1
       End Select
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have a `/` at the end that prevent you from deleting the folder, see the correction.

Also, you can change the `Dir(...)` to only select `txt` files to avoid deleting the rest of the files!

Here is the code :

```
iYesNo = MsgBox("Do the patients and barcode match the setup sheet?", vbYesNoCancel)
Select Case iYesNo
    Case vbYes
        GoTo Line2
    Case vbNo
        MsgBox ("Doesn't match! Please enter again")
        MyFolder = Directory ' delete all txt files in the folder
        MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "*.txt")
        Do Until MyFile = ""
            Kill MyFile
            MyFile = Dir
        Loop

        RmDir Left(MyFolder, Len(MyFolder) - 1) ' delete folder
        GoTo Line1
End Select
```

Comment: So that change did work however now I am getting a file not found on the `Kill MyFile` line, but there are 3 txt files in the directory to delete.  Thank you :).

Comment: Strange... I didn't changed the part regarding `Kill`, it is just supposed to filter the text files... Good luck with that! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA's access rights to files depends on if Excel is launched with or without admin rights.  Find EXCEL.EXE and launch it with or without a right-click and run-as-administrator.  Check what your VBA does.  With admin rights have it create a text file.  Then try to open that file without non-admin rights.  Although it may matter what folder you do this test in.